# Synchronous and Asynchronous Communication

Tags: asynchronous

In Synchronous, the server sends a message to a client and waits for a response. The program is blocked until a response message is returned to server.

In Asynchronous, the server sends a message to a client and waits for a response. While waiting, the server program is not blocking and can continue to execute. However, when a response is returned back to server, server will receive and sends message again.

My question here is synchronous communication can only have one server communicate with one client? However, asynchronous communication allows one server to communicate with multiple clients?

I am read a few articles and try to understand but I am still confused with synchronous and asynchronous communication. Hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: "server sends a message to a client and waits for a response"
no, usually client sends a message to a servers and waits for response.

Comment: servers can usually handle requests from multiple clients at the same time. clients can also communicate with multiple servers at the same time.
in synchronous protocols, the client waits for the response. in asynchronous protocols, the server might accept the request and provide an answer later.